# Getting OutOfMemory exception in android app while loading new activity

Tags: android

```
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at xxx.PickLeafCell.<init>(PickLeafCell.java:38)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at xxx.CueFileListAdapter.getView(CueFileListAdapter.java:108)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1272)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1558)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:909)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     ... 34 more
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
12-11 23:38:42.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4261):     ... 38 more
```

Comment: Definitely nice to look at after a successful working day.

Comment: I put null for all reference used in my activity in OnDestroy() method..
memory still increasing when I checked allocated memory from DDMS tool.

Comment: this may be because memory leaks. do you have some classes holding referenc to your `Activity` or `Context` that do not get deallocated. You should use Eclispe MAT to analyze the hprof file dumped from DDMS Perspective.

Comment: Threads still running, holding references? References in Application object? Everything's possible.

Comment: No... I checked a lot... 
When I started activty first, my app only uses 10 Mb of heap.. then I finish same activty and started another actvity.. now heap increases.. 
I think GC not deallocated memory of my previous activty..
I am sure about one thing, activity stack not keeping my previous activity.. but memory still not freed :(

Comment: @ArunMohan just to let you know, you will not find bitmaps in heap memory, because bitmaps are allocated in the native memory (pre honeycomb).

Comment: Ok.. All images are located in res/drawable folder.. Does GC dealloc memory that used for loading bitmaps in Imageviews?

Answer (score 1):

You are loading bitmaps that are too large in size. `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`. There is a solution though. You need to decode the bitmap to a lower resolution [[how to do so]](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

Seems that you are loading a big image. For this you have multiple options:
1. use BitmapOptions to get the size, calculate the scale and then decode only with the scale that you need

1. resize the image directly on your PC in order to fit a device need.

An must read page for this topic is here:
[Android developers](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

PS. On important thing here is that you should NEVER decode an image on the UI thread. This will affect your app performance.